# Difference between Visual Studio Code Community and Open Source editions

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the difference in functionality between Microsoft Visual Studio Code:

- "Open Source"  - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode ([MIT License](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/LICENSE.txt))
- "Community Edition" - https://code.visualstudio.com/ ([Microsoft licence](https://code.visualstudio.com/License))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Microsoft VS code really open source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4288)

Comment: As I understand it... The Github page is only the source code repository. Source code itself has a difference license than binaries. There're third-party binaries available or you can build your own.

Answer (score 1):

The [Visual Studio Code FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_what-does-built-on-open-source-mean) distingishes them thus:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Code is a Microsoft licensed distribution of 'Code - OSS' that includes Microsoft proprietary assets (such as icons) and features (Visual Studio Marketplace integration, small aspects of enabling Remote Development). While these additions make up a very small percentage of the overall distribution code base, it is more accurate to say that Visual Studio Code is "built" on open source, rather than "is" open source, because of these differences.

[Differences between the repository and Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Differences-between-the-repository-and-Visual-Studio-Code) lists the following changes to the OSS version before having the Microsoft Licence slapped on:

- Icons, Product Name (e.g. "Microsoft Visual Studio Code"), Documentation
- Visual Studio Marketplace Integration
- Extension Recommendations
- Remote Development
- Enable Proprietary Debug Adapters, Visual Studio Code Server
- Extensions Using Proposed APIs
- Telemetry, Surveys, Crash Reporting
- Update Services